# Turn two uint32_t into a uint64_t, then turn back into a double based on the bit pattern not the value

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, c++14

the code that hands me the two uint32_t essentially takes a double, in binary cuts it in half so half the bytes are in one variable and the other half are in the other.

My program need to take them and stitch it back together.

```
int x = 0b00111101110100011101110111110111;
int y = 0b11100111001100101010000110111001;

uint64_t int64 = (long long) x << 32 | y;
double d = static_cast<double> (int64);
```

this is what i have so far and it doesnt give the correct output at all.

it gives:       1.84467e+19
it should be:   6.49999999999999952595094363798E-11

Thanks

Comment: So what is that incorrect output you get??

Comment: You probably want `static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t), "!"); memcpy(&d, &int64, sizeof(double));`.

Comment: You also don't wanna be using `static_cast` in [tag:c]. So I removed that tag.

Comment: You don't want to do a static_cast, because that will try to convert the integer value in "int64" into a floating point value. Instead, use a memcpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C, you can do it this way:

```
const uint32_t x = 0x3DD1DDF7;
const uint32_t y = 0xE732A1B9;
const uint64_t z = ((uint64_t) x << 32) | y;
double d;
memcpy(&d, &z, sizeof d);
```

But I'm not sure, there could be an endian issue here since this code is quite hairy. I'm getting 6.5e-11 as the output.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
unsigned int x = 0b00111101110100011101110111110111;
unsigned int y = 0b11100111001100101010000110111001; // Must be unsigned!

uint64_t int64 = ((long long) x << 32) | y; // Parentheses highly recommended for
                                            // readability (but not strictly necessary)
double d = reinterpret_cast<double&> (int64); // Definitely not portable!
```

Your code had two problems:

- the signed integer `y` was being converted to `long long`, which meant that the high word was `0xFFFFFFFF`. `x` and `y` should be declared `unsigned`.
- `static_cast` converts the value, not the bit pattern. Use `reinterpret_cast` to retain the bit pattern. (As Mgetz points out in a comment, there is now (since C++20) an official way to get this done: [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast). This doesn't rely on undefined behaviour, as long as `double` and `int64` are the same size.)

Answer (score 0):

How about this code for your purpose. example

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t tsc = 0xdeaddeadc0dec0de;
    uint32_t MSB = *((uint32_t*)&tsc+1);
    uint32_t LSB = *((uint32_t*)&tsc);
    std::printf("low   %x high %x \n", LSB,MSB);
    uint64_t MLSB = 0;
    *((uint32_t*)&MLSB) = LSB;
    *((uint32_t*)&MLSB+1) = MSB;
    std::printf("highlow %lx \n", MLSB);
    uint64_t LMSB = 0;
    *((uint32_t*)&LMSB+1) = LSB;
    *((uint32_t*)&LMSB) = MSB;
    std::printf("lowhigh %lx \n", LMSB);
}
```

solution to your problem

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int x = 0b01000000001101110000000000000000;
int y = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000;
    uint64_t int64 = 0;
    *((uint32_t*)&int64+1) = x;
    *((uint32_t*)&int64) = y;
    double d = *((double*)&int64);
    std::printf("double d %e \n", d);
    std::printf("int int64 %llx \n", int64);
    
x = 0b00111101110100011101110111110111;
y = 0b11100111001100101010000110111001;
    *((uint32_t*)&int64+1) = x;
    *((uint32_t*)&int64) = y;
    d = *((double*)&int64);
    std::printf("double d %e \n", d);
    std::printf("int int64 %llx \n", int64);

}
```

result 
double d 2.300000e+01 
int int64 4037000000000000 
double d 6.500000e-11 
int int64 3dd1ddf7e732a1b9

or without referencing problem

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
unsigned char  x[] = {0b01000000,0b00110111,0b00000000,0b00000000};
unsigned char  y[] = {0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000};
    uint64_t int64 = 0;
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+7) = x[0];
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+6) = x[1];
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+5) = x[2];
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+4) = x[3];
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+3) = y[0];
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+2) = y[1];
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+1) = y[2];
    *((unsigned char*)&int64+0) = y[3];
    double d =0;
    *((unsigned char*)&d+7) = x[0];
    *((unsigned char*)&d+6) = x[1];
    *((unsigned char*)&d+5) = x[2];
    *((unsigned char*)&d+4) = x[3];
    *((unsigned char*)&d+3) = y[0];
    *((unsigned char*)&d+2) = y[1];
    *((unsigned char*)&d+1) = y[2];
    *((unsigned char*)&d+0) = y[3];
    //*((double*)&int64);
    std::printf("double d %e \n", d);
    std::printf("int int64 %lu \n", int64);
    
}
```